# Cron job delete file by name like

Tags: cron

I need a script for delete file with name like:
MT11255-ML-LS-FLANNEL-ELEMENTAL-1-cropped-800x80064.jpg

my script now :
find /home/path_ke_folder/*-cropped-*x*.jpg -exec rm {}

but there's nothing happen

Answer (score 1):

- The pattern you gave doesn't match the file. That filename doesn't end in `-cropped-x.jpg`.
- The shell will expand the wildcard, there's no need for `find`.

`rm /home/path_ke_folder/*-cropped-*.jpg`